# how to Allow ! but block consecutive !! in regular expression in shell scripting in the below code

Tags: regex, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

default_pwd="mysql_password"
script_pwd="template!123"
echo $default_pwd
echo $script_pwd
if [ $default_pwd == $script_pwd ]
then
    echo "They match"
else
    if [ `expr "$script_pwd" : ".*[!]{2}$.*"` -gt 0];
    then
            echo "Contain consecutive !! special character"
    else
            echo "valid password"
    fi
fi
```

**Expected Result:
it should echo "consecutive !! special character" when  script_pwd has !! for ex template!!123
and
it should echo "valid password" when the script_pwd for example is template!123**

Comment: Beware that `$` looks for an end of string. Then your regex looks like: match 2 consecutive occurences of `!` immediately before end of string. If you want a match anywhere in the string you could use only `!+`.

Comment: Do not forget the space before the `]`. Try to forget that `expr` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=~` operator to match for regular expressions.

```
default_pwd="mysql_password"
script_pwd="test!!123"
echo $default_pwd
echo $script_pwd
if [ $default_pwd == $script_pwd ]
then
    echo "They match"
else
    re='.*[!]{2}.*' # edit: removed character range validation
    if [[ $script_pwd =~ $re ]];
    then
            echo "Contain consecutive !! special character"
    else
            echo "valid password"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: This works for test!!123 properly but if password is changed to test!123 also the output is
    mysql_password
    test!123
    Contain consecutive !! special character

Comment: My apologies. I had written the regex to validate upto 2 ! characters. I've edited to remove that validation now.

Answer (score 0):

with bash you can try

```
 pwd='temp!late!123';[ "${pwd/\!\!/}" = "$pwd" ] && echo true|| echo false

 pwd='temp!!late!123';[ "${pwd/\!\!/}" = "$pwd" ] && echo true|| echo false
```

In your script with posix shell

```
#!/bin/sh
script_pwd="template!!123"
echo $script_pwd
[ "$script_pwd" == "${script_pwd#*!!}" ] && \
  echo "valid password" || \
  echo "Contain consecutive !! special character"
```

Comment: does it work without if condition then didnt understand how to incorporate this in my script can you please elaborate the line